# Extract values from CSV and place it in a new column within the same CSV file using NiFi

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I have a CSV file from which i need to extract two values like 'UutId & Test' and  place it in the last column (filename).How can i pull/extract values from same CSV file and place it in the last column of the same CSV file called 'filename' which is blank(without any values right now). 
If possible please tell what processor and configs to use?TIA

For reference i am attaching CSV file snapshot of value i want to add in the last column called 'filename' repeated in the whole CSV records.

**Values to be extracted**
[image: Values to be extracted]

**The column in which the values should be placed**
[image: The column in which the values should be placed]

**List queue after GetFile**
[image: List queue]

The list queue after playing the `UpdateRecord` processor makes it blank file.

**List queue after playing UpdateRecord**
[image: List queue after playing UpdateRecord]
please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract filname and store the name in a new column in csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846387/extract-filname-and-store-the-name-in-a-new-column-in-csv-file)

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman I checked the duplicacy. There is only one unique column 'filename'. Any other suggestion or way to do this? TIA

Comment: The input file doesn't look like a CSV file. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman It is CSV only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UpdateRecord processor below configs

in **CSVRecordSetWriter** controller service add filename column with string type as last field in the avro schema.

**UpdateRecord Configs:**

[image]

Add new property in UpdateRecord processor as

**/filename**

```
concat(/UutId,/Test)
```

As we are using **Record Path Value** as **Replacement Value Strategy**

now update record processor will concat UutId,Test values to filename column value.

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/189642/update-the-contents-of-flowfile-by-using-updaterec.html) link for more details regarding Update Record processor.

Comment: I followed what you said but the output CSV file is getting blank and only in the last column i.e. 'filename' the values entered are 'null null' (2 times). What to do about that?TIA

Comment: @shrads null is because of the record path doesn't exists, these record path is case sensitive. Make sure you are using correct column names. **if the error still exists update question with ur new configs of the controller services and sample records**

Comment: please help. Thank you